# How to create Log file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, windows, logging, cmd, ssis

I want to create a log file in SSIS. I know how to create through management studio, but I wanted to run my SSIS package through Command Prompt.
Can you help me find the Windows commands for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the a new connection string inside of Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS). where you have to specify the path of Log file...i mean here path will be D:\Sample_Examples\Log.log... and name of the connection manager will be Log.log
so now the command prompt will get changed into

```
dtexec /f "C:\\Package.dtsx" /l "DTS.LogProviderTextFile";"Log.log"
```

instead of

```
dtexec /f "C:\\Package.dtsx" /l "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;D:\Sample_Examples\Log.log"
```

we cant specify a direct path after DTS.LogProviderTextFile...because of that only i got error...

Thank you very much for the suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the /L option, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx); however, you can also set Logging up in a much easier and finer way through the SSIS>Logging menu in Visual Studio.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: yes i used 
dtexec /f "C:\\Package.dtsx" /l "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;D:\Sample_Examples\Log.log"
like this...
but i am getting two errors like
  1. The connection "D:\Sample_Examples\Log.log" is not found. This error is thrown by connections collection when the specific connection element is not found
  2. connection manager is nt found
any idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

In your SSIS you need to create and configure an SSIS Log provider before you can use it. Look into [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes i have check the link but in that they are explaining how to enable Logging thorugh BIDS...
I wanted to create the Logging using DOS commands...
any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this another way, without going into your SSIS package.

Create a batch file and run DTEXEC in a new instance of CMD, i.e.:

CMD /C DTEXEC *your package and args* > *log file*

When you do this, you can run this batch file and get your log file.

See http://richarddingwall.name/2009/01/26/capture-the-output-from-a-scheduled-task/ for more details

Comment: One note on this approach: be careful about invoking an SSIS package this way and then trying to do an logic around the %ERRORLEVEL% variable. Supposedly this should be non-zero when your package errors out, but I've seen it return zero when the package clearly failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a connection manager for the log provider; however; there is no documentation on how to do this if you are using a custom log provider.